# React stripe 3d secure

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement 3d security with stripe + react and cannot find one example where it's shown how to do it

I found this example https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously#web and if you input card

```
4000000000003063    required    Yes     Yes     3D Secure must be completed for a charge to be successful.
```

inside example 3d secure popup shows up, but react example is not that and they also included sandbox which is nice which leads to https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-official-q1loc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

and that is supposed to be react example but when you input credit card `4000000000003063` the 3d security popup isn't shown it just creates payment intent which is not what's needed

**Is there a way to trigger popup without stripe elements?**

or

**Is there a react example with 3d security?**

There is also https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment which is just pure html css js?

Thank you

Comment: There is a complete React example for Elements here: https://github.com/stripe-samples/react-elements-card-payment You can also clone this sample locally using the Stripe CLI:  https://stripe.com/docs/cli/samples/create. You can then use the regulatory test cards to test things out: https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards